# WrongTargetException in Hazelcast cluster

Tags: java, hazelcast

I was running a POC with two members of hazelcast cluster, with 3.4.1 version of hazelcast.
I observed a strange behavior, where one member was continuously throwing WrongTargetException.
It was a rare scenario which I was able to replicate with following sequence of events :

Assume I am running cluster with two members say X and Y.

1. Unplugged Y from the the cluster so it becomes unresponsive.
2. X thinks Y is not responding so it remove it from clusters.
3. Plugged in Y again, Y assumes it has not received any response/heart-beat
   from X, so think X is dead, and it kicked X out from the cluster.
4. X begins to throw WrongTargetException soon.

While searching on google I find same issue is described here https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/3395.

So would like to know if this has been fixed now, and what is preferred version that should be used. Please consider that I am already using 3.4.1 for other applications as well, so don't want to do a massive change while upgrading to latest version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the issue https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/3395 is fixed in the version 3.7.

So you can try with the latest Hazelcast version: `4.0.1`. Or if you don't want to upgrade the major version, then try `3.12.6`.